# xauth is unable to write to my .Xauthority file

Tags: arch-linux, x-server, xauth

I run Arch Linux with the window manager BSPWM (so no DE) and recently I have been having a problem with my *.Xauthority* file.

I am no longer able to start my X server because it is unable to write to my *.Xauthority* file. When I tried deleting my *.Xauthority* file in hopes of arch creating a new *.Xauthority* file for me when I logged back in, a new *.Xauthority* file is not being created.

I've tried recreating the *.Xauthority* file manually and changing its permissions, but it still has not worked. In addition, I have a *.Xauthority-n* file in my home directory, I am not sure what this does - but when deleted, it reappears when I log back in.

When the *.Xauthority-n* and the *.Xauthority* files are present, on startx it gives me this error:

```
xauth: unable to write authority file ~/.Xauthority-n
```

I am not sure why it doesn't try to use the regular *.Xauthority* file.

How do I get xauth to be able to write to my .Xauthority file? And what is the purpose of the .Xauthority-n file and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried using `startx`?

Comment: Yeah, when I run startx it also gives me the same error and then just shows a black screen.

Comment: try this `xinit /usr/bin/startxfce4 -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc -nolisten tcp vt1 -auth /tmp/user.xinit`

Comment: replace `/usr/bin/startxfce4` with your DE path

Comment: I do not use a DE, I use Arch Linux with the window manager, BSPWM.

Answer (score 6):

When `xauth` is updating the `.Xauthority` file, it will initially write a new version of it as `.Xauthority-n`. Once the file is completely written, it will move/rename it to `.Xauthority`, causing the old version of the file to be deleted at the same time.

This relies on the fact that rename/move operations within a single POSIX-compliant filesystem are supposed to be *atomic*: the operation cannot ever stop half-way, but either it will complete successfully or the old file will be left unchanged.

If the `xauth` command finds that the `.Xauthority-n` file is already present, it assumes it means another instance of `xauth` command is already doing some changes, and refuses to do anything. So this also protects the file from corruption caused by multiple instances of `xauth` running at the same time as the same user.

The fact that a `.Xauthority-n` file remains in your home directory suggests that an earlier copy of `xauth` was terminated in mid-operation before it could execute the rename/move operation for some reason.

You should log out of the X GUI, then login either remotely or using the text-based virtual console, and then delete *both* `.Xauthority` *and* `.Xauthority-n`. After that, the GUI login should work normally, unless you have some other problem that prevents the system from creating/overwriting the `.Xauthority` file in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I'd the same issue.

Comment: I run xauth, and then It shows like this:$ xauth
Using authority file /home/administrator/.Xauthority
xauth> 
Am I in right track? so now should I delete  /home/administrator/.Xauthority ???